# Firebase deployed function raises CORS errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, cors

I am trying to deploy a simple cloud function on firebase, together with a ajax front-end call of that function. The front-end call sends a .pdf file to the cloud function, that further process it. Both FE and BE were tested on firebase:emulators and were working as expected. The biggest problem is that I am not sure how to debug this problem, because even if the console throws a CORS error, it is probably something else. The last log from the firebase cloud functions console says

> Function execution took 29 ms, finished with status code: 404

while in the console, the error is

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://us-central1-paperfire-ada3a.cloudfunctions.net/api/upload' from origin 'https://paperfire-ada3a.web.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Cors is set up using the express library in the backend. Here is the backend code:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const cors = require('cors')
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const { getStorage, ref, uploadBytes, getDownloadURL } = require('firebase-admin/storage');
const express = require('express');
const pdfParse = require('pdf-parse');
const { OpenAI } = require("openai"); 
const openai = new OpenAI({apiKey:'api-key'});
const app = express();
var serviceAccount = require("./paperfire-ada3a-firebase-adminsdk-k5cno-361bebbe1e.json");


const MAX_FILE_SIZE = 16 * 1024 * 1024; // 16 MB
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "https://paperfire-ada3a-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app",
    storageBucket: 'gs://paperfire-ada3a.appspot.com'
  });


// Automatically allow cross-origin requests
app.use(cors({ origin: true }));

// Handling preflight requests
app.options('*', cors());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Welcome to the PDF processing API. Use the /upload endpoint to upload files.');
});

app.post('/upload', async (req, res) => {
...
});

const runtimeOpts = {
    timeoutSeconds: 300, // Set timeout to 5 minutes
    memory: '1GB' // Adjust memory based on your function's needs
  };

exports.api = functions.runWith(runtimeOpts).https.onRequest(app);
```

And here is the front-end call to the /upload route:

```
 firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true).then(function(idToken) {

            var form = $('#uploadForm')[0];
            var formData = new FormData(form);
            
            // Perform the AJAX request
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'https://us-central1-paperfire-ada3a.cloudfunctions.net/api/upload',
                data: formData,
                contentType: false, // This is required for FormData with file upload
                processData: false, // Also required for FormData with file upload
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + idToken  // Include the ID token in the request headers
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log(response.extractedText)
                    if(response.audioUrl) {
...
```

The main question here is what is wrong with my cloud function and how do I figure it out for other cases in the future? The console and the log doesn't seem to help too much, while the emulator environment is not able to fill all the test cases.
Thank you very much, I appreciate any help!

Comment: Do you have Funtions IAP authentication enabled? https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/customizing#allowing_http_options_requests_cors_preflight

Comment: Use the browser debugger (inspect) to determine if the request is complete and if the error happens on the HTTP OPTIONS request. Another test is to turn off authentication to make sure your code works and that CORS is configured correctly.

Comment: the fact that `finished with status code: 404` could mean that all the server code you've posted isn't even being executed for the request - are you sure the code you posted actually handles the `/api` path?

Comment: @JohnHanley I don't have IAP auth enabled, I was not aware that is needed for firebase function setup, I will try to enable it now. Also, I did use the browser debugger, and it seems that the preflight fails with  `403 Forbidden`, with `Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin`. I might try to turn off auth to make sure that CORS works well

Comment: @JaromandaX I am not sure how to check if the code actually handles the `/api` path, as far as I see in the console, the request goes to the correct path

Comment: so, if you put a console.log where you currently have `...` (in `app.post('/upload', async (req, res) => {`) you can see the request coming in?

Comment: No, it seems that nothing of that code actually executes

Comment: @JaromandaX I also eliminated the auth from the front-end, but the error is the same, so I guess the route is never called. I double checked and the function trigger is correct, and also I can see that the function gets invoked in the firebase console, so I am really confused

Comment: `No, it seems that nothing of that code actually executes` well, then the path is wrong

Comment: The trigger url from the cloud functions console is: `Trigger URL 
https://us-central1-paperfire-ada3a.cloudfunctions.net/api`, while my url in the ajax call is `url: 'https://us-central1-paperfire-ada3a.cloudfunctions.net/api/upload'`, because I have an endpoint /upload in the backend. I also tried without /upload, but it behaves the same. Am I missing something?

Comment: The request includes the HTTP Authorization header with an Identity Token. That is why I asked if IAP is enabled. If the preflight fails (OPTIONS), then the API endpoint is not called. Test from the command line using a tool such as `CURL` so that you can see requests and responses. The browser will not show the HTTP response for CORS problems. Tip: do not include the Authorization header if you do not have IAP enabled for the function.

Comment: @JohnHanley the Auth header is needed because I use the token further in the backend to identify the user in the database and to increase its authentication count. Furthermore, I tested everything in Postman, and I had a few issues in the code (Bearer with a capital B doesn't work), but now the request from Postman works as expected. The front-end has the exact same problem, the OPTIONS method still fail with `403 Forbidden`, and it seems that it doesn't matter what I set from the backend, it doesn't get executed anyway.

Comment: The last time I checked, you cannot use the Authorization header for your own purposes. You must use a different header. I wrote an answer with details on Stack Overflow if you want to search for that. However, that might not be the current state. This page has more details: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service

Comment: Note: Postman does not check or enforce CORS. Just because it works using Postman does not mean it will work in a browser. However, Postman is a good debugging tool to see the request and response headers.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thank you! I knew that Postman does not check for CORS errors, but it was useful to debug other errors, in order to make sure that there is a CORS problem. I tried to manually set all the response headers from postman to the cloud function, but again, nothing happened. Also, if I eliminate the auth, the 403 Forbidden error gets thrown directly on the request(not on the preflight), so it doesn't change much. Something is still missing

Comment: 403 error. What is generating that error? IAP or your code? To make sure your requests are getting past the Google Frontend (GFE) create an endpoint that you can test with. IAP is integrated with the GFE which becomes a load balancing authorization proxy.

Comment: Your problem, as I see it, is that you don't know what is not working. Use the classic debugging techniques of dividing your problem in two. Then repeat until you now exactly what is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @John Hanley mentioned in the comments, the issue was not with my cors setup. The function was never reaching my cloud function due to Google Frontend blocking my request. The only way I was able to solve this issue was to access my cloud function from the Google Cloud console and set the permissions for Cloud functions Invoker to `allUsers`. This is a temporal solution and maybe other answers will provide more context, but the problem is solved for now. I still have to figure out a way to set this variable for production, because it is a security risk.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue on deploying a new project and the word "allUsers" above reminded me that I had this a couple of years ago too - when deploying for the first time.

It seems that new 2nd Gen Firebase HTTP Functions are initially deployed as "private" (in Cloud Run) and you have to specifically open them up to be public - and not require an IAM authorisation.

I was also getting a 403 error from "Google Frontend" in the OPTIONS prefetch of all my API calls from within a Firebase-hosted site. Of course the browser complains about CORS not being fulfilled, which is always the case when an API isn't working at all - and so often lures you into thinking its a CORS problem. It's not a CORS issue - it's a generic 403 "permission denied" from the proxy in-front of the app so editing app files and CORS config won't do anything.

I can't see anything to explain the IAM requirement in the basic documentation here though where you'd expect it (for a typical public API):
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events?gen=2nd

but while I read the part about "Integrating with Firebase Hosting" which is about proxying/redirecting function calls via your public hosted domain https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions

interestingly there's a warning here under ["Deploying"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions#deploy-function) which warns

> Caution: New HTTP and HTTP callable functions deployed with any Firebase CLI lower than version 7.7.0 are private by default and throw HTTP 403 errors when invoked. Either [explicitly make these functions public](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access-iam#allowing_unauthenticated_http_function_invocation) or update your Firebase CLI before you deploy any new functions.

And if you read the "make these public" part" it explains how to add the "allUsers" permission, but via a nicer UI in the Cloud Run service. ( I think last time I did this was via IAM config)

- View Functions at GCP console.cloud.google.com/functions/list
- For each "HTTP" function:

  - Under RHS "..." menu, "Go To Cloud Run Service"
  - Security > Authentication > Allow unauthenticated invocations
    *"Tick this if you are creating a public API or website."*

[image]

This adds the permissions to the function without you having to mess around with IAMs and service accounts.

After this my functions immediately started working.

My Firebase CLI is version 13.1.0, so perhaps there's another reason for these functions to be deployed as private. Perhaps they're meant to be and the docs are wrong/missing?

UPDATE: I have just deployed my application to a new Firebase project for the first time, and found that some of the Functions were set up with public access and some of them not! It seemed random. I did have some permission errors on the first deployment, because the automatic enabling of some required APIs took "longer than expected", and so I had to deploy again to get the functions to be created, so this might have led to the differences - which is a bit worrying!

I might delete all the functions and redeploy. And in future I will enable all APIs well in advance to avoid this apparent race-hazard.